# validate textbox string for comma and Ampersand

Tags: .net, regex

I need to validate the text box value with comma and Ampersand means if user enter , or & symbol in text box it should show error .

i have tried Regex for this but it didnt work the way i want

```
([a-zA-Z])*([,]|[&])([a-zA-Z])*
```

anyone knows the regex for the same?

Comment: define "Does not work the way I want". I ran your regex through a bunch of tests and it does indeed match anything with a comma and/or an ampersand.

Comment: @jamiec i meant if the entered value by user contain , or & then only it should throw error but now if the string does not contain any of the above mention symbol then also it is showing error.

Comment: Please show piece of code you're using and some sample input strings with expected result.

Comment: @avinashRaj the regex u gave only work for character but when i put any number of any other symbol it shows error but in my case i need  validation for only ',' and '&' symbol

Comment: then try this `^[^,&]+$`

Answer (score 1):

i think here is what u need.
make a character class in which put , and & eg [,&] and any symbol you want to match be careful for escape characters. than match it against the TextBox like this.

```
    Regex regex = new Regex("[,&]");
    if (regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
```

and wrap this code behind the event or match function you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try below regex:

```
[,&]
```

if regex matches then your text contain ',' or '&' and you should display error.

**Example**

```
String rx = "[,&]";
String yourString = "hi & my name?";

if(!Pattern.compile(rx).matcher(yourString).find()){
    System.out.println(yourString+" is correct");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Comment: i tried using ur solution , but its only accepting , and & but not accepting anything else. i want reserve of this.... How to negate this regex??